# How do I replace certain characters in multiple lines of a text file using Python?

Tags: python

I'm new to Python so please bear with me. I have a text file named names.txt. The contents of that file are:

```
6,pon01.bf:R1.S1.LT1.PON10.ONT12
10,pon01.bf:R1.S1.LT1.PON10.ONT16
11,pon01.bf:R1.S1.LT1.PON10.ONT17
12,pon01.bf:R1.S1.LT1.PON10.ONT18
```

I need to be able to replace the "R", "S", "LT", "PON" and "ONT" with a "/", remove everything else and add "/1/1" to each line. The end result should look like this:

```
1/1/1/10/12/1/1,
1/1/1/10/16/1/1,
1/1/1/10/17/1/1,
1/1/1/10/18/1/1,
```

Below is my code:

```
import os
import re
import sys




file = open("/home/Scripts/names.txt", "r")
delnode = file.readline()

port = "/1/1"

for line in delnode:

   delnode = delnode.split('R')[-1]
   delnode = delnode.replace(".S", "/").replace(".LT", "/").replace(".PON", "/").replace(".ONT", "/")

print delnode + port

file.close()
```

The output of this script is:

```
1/1/1/10/12
/1/1
```

It only reads the first line in the text file. Appreciate any help!

Comment: re.sub https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub

Comment: Loop over the lines instead of the `delnode`. E.g.: `for line in file:`

Comment: And you get the /1/1 in a new line because you are currently a newline character. Use delnode.strip() to remove it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating over the first line with `readlines()`, just iterate over the file and `strip()` every line to skip the `\n` at end of lines.

```
file = open("/home/Scripts/names.txt", "r")
port = "/1/1"
for line in file:
   line = line.strip().split('R')[-1]
   line = line.replace(".S", "/").replace(".LT", "/").replace(".PON", "/").replace(".ONT", "/")
   print line + port
```

Comment: That works! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This wil read all file at once and split it into lines into one list.

```
file.read().split()
```

This list you can then iterate line by

```
import os
import re
import sys


file = open("/home/Scripts/names.txt", "r")
for delnode in file.read().split():
    port = "/1/1"

    # Splitting delnode, you want to get second half of text, therefore index 1 (0 -> 1st index, 1-> 2nd index)
    delnode = delnode.split('R')[1] # [-1] also works, but you are taking the last item
    delnode = delnode.replace(".S", "/").replace(".LT", "/").replace(".PON", "/").replace(".ONT", "/")

    print delnode + port
file.close()
```

In console:

```
1/1/1/10/12/1/1
1/1/1/10/16/1/1
1/1/1/10/17/1/1
1/1/1/10/18/1/1
>>>
```

**NOTE:**

I only modified your solution, so you dont have hard time understanding what has happened